# How to add delay time into line of code on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

im trying to do a function that when user move cursor over image it will show a preview. So im taking the src of the image that fired the event and im changing it into the path of different images.

```
$('#image').hover(function(){
    var src = "";
    var elem = $(this);
    for (var i=2; i<16; i++) {
        src = elem.attr('src').split('.');
        src[3] = i; 
        src = src.toString();
    src = src.split(',').join('.');
    elem.attr('src', src);
    }
});
```

The problem is here, when i try to do something like below, putting a delay into every preview it doesn't work as i want.

```
$('#image').hover(function(){
    var src = "";
    var elem = $(this);
    for (var i=2; i<16; i++) {
        src = elem.attr('src').split('.');
        src[3] = i; 
        src = src.toString();
        src = src.split(',').join('.');
        setTimeout(function() {
            elem.attr('src', src);
        }, 800);
    }
});
```

How i can solve it? I'm working with that problem for +2h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you cant use setTimeout inside a for loop..
Instead of that use setInterval..

```
 $('#image').hover(function () {
    var src = "";
    var elem = $(this);
    var i = 2;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (i < 16) {
            src = elem.attr('src').split('.');
            src[3] = i;
            src = src.toString();
            src = src.split(',').join('.');

            elem.attr('src', src);
            i++;
        } else {
            i = 2;
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it worked fine. I was trying a lot of stuff inside the loop and no matter what i've was doing the preview just jump across to the end. So the problem here is that i can't use a delay inside a loop. Really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#image').hover(function(){
    var src = "";
    var elem = $(this);
    for (var i=2; i<16; i++) {
        src = elem.attr('src').split('.');
        src[3] = i; 
        src = src.toString();
        src = src.split(',').join('.');

$(elem).delay(800).animate({zoom:1},0,function(){$(this).src(src);});
    }
});
```